# Compile C#, so that it runs with the speed of C++

Tags: c#, c++

Alright, so I wanted to ask if it's actually possible to make a parser from c# to c++.
So that code written in C# would be able to run as fast as code written in C++.
Is it actually possible to do? I'm not asking how hard is it going to be.

Comment: Very hard. Really. Why don't you write C++ in the first place ?

Comment: @Alexandre C. The thing is, to use C# with the compile speed of C++, You think it's possible?

Comment: Can you please rephrase? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Rich Porter: this is nonsense. C# is fast enough for most uses. If you have a particular function which takes too much time, then you may contemplate writing it in C++ and `pinvoke` it. Writing a fully fledged parser for C# to convert it to C++ is a very difficult task.

Comment: Do you want the **compiled code** to be as fast as C++ - or do you want the **process of compiling** to be as fast as with (what?) C++ compiler?

Comment: @yas4891 Yes, I want it to be compiled as fast as C++.

Comment: Since when is C# compilation slower than C++ compilation? There isn't a single reason that should be the case (quite the contrary, C++ should be much slower to compile), and reality seems to conform to theory.

Comment: @Rich: i a somewhat hilarious way, you manage to keep the ambiguity. I'm sure you can make C# code compile as slowly as average C++ projects by including `sleep 30` in your build scripts

Comment: @Rich how you measured compilation time?

Comment: @Delnan, I'm sure the OP is talking about the running speed of the program, not the compilation speed.

Comment: @Johan: Read again. Granted, most of the post is **very** unclear and can be interpreted as that, but in response to yas4891, OP stated "I want it to be compiled as fast as C++".

Comment: @delnan, that's a very confused notion, C++ is **definitely** not known for its fast compile times. If the OP was talking about Pascal I'd understand, it that's just silly, methinks the OP is confusing compilation with running and doesn't really know what the word `compile` actually means.

Comment: @Johan: Hey, don't tell that *me* (have you read my first comment? I'm saying exactly the same thing!), tell it OP. This wouldn't be the first question asked on an unverified, wrong premise. *Maybe* OP doesn't know what compilation is (quite a few don't, but most of them only confuse it with AOT compilation to machine code), but that seems less likely that a wrong premise (Occam's razor anyone?).

Comment: @Rich, do you know what the word `compile` means? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler, hint: it has nothing to do with actually using the program.

Comment: @delnan, I meant running time.

Comment: Have 200 source file in project. C# would compile slow, and C++ would compile fast - if incremental linking is enabled.

Comment: For some reason, I still didn't get any proven and good answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What makes you think that translating your C# code to C++ would *magically* make it faster?

Languages don't have a speed. Assuming that C# code is slower (I'll get back to that), it is because of what that code *does* (including the implicit requirements placed by C#, such as bounds checking on arrays), and not because of the language it is written in.

If you converted your C# code to C++, it would *still* need to do bounds checking on arrays, because the original source code expected this to happen, so it would have to do just as much work.

Moreover, C# often isn't slower than C++. There are plenty of benchmarks floating around on the internet, generally showing that for the most part, C# is *as fast* as (or faster than) C++. Only when you spend *a lot* of time optimizing your code, does C++ become faster.

If you want faster code, you need to write code that requires less work to execute, not try to change the source language. That's just cargo-cult programming at its worst. You once saw some efficient code, and that was written in C++, so now you try to make things C++, in the hope of attracting any efficiency that might be passing by.

It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Lets be clear, C++ **can** always be faster than C#, the question is: are you a good enough programmer to actually **make** it faster AND does it matter. Often times 90%+ of the time is either spend in a critical loop, or waiting for data to come streaming from some slow source.

Comment: @Johan: Why? How do you know? Where in the C++ or C# spec does it say "And it should always be possible to optimize C++ to be faster than C#"? If you want to be clear, bring some facts to the table. Don't just say "Let's be clear" and then start talking about your unproven assumptions

Comment: Of course, *in its current implementation*, C# has some unavoidable overhead in some cases, such as the time to load the .NET framework which increases startup times. But that's a property of the current implementation; it certainly has nothing to do with C# *as a language*.

Comment: I was talking about the current implementation with management code, .net runtime and garbage collection. Which does indeed have nothing to do with the C# language as such. I'm a bit surprised by the _hash_ tone of your first reaction, the C# has a lot of fans, it hardly needs you to defend it. By which I mean it **must** be doing a lot of things right.

Comment: I'm not defending anything. I'm making a very fundamental point that languages do not have a speed. How many things C# does right or wrong is completely irrelevant.

Comment: "... in the hope of attracting any efficiency that might be passing by." - I love that phrase. It makes me think of all the voodoo code I've had to put up with.

Answer (score 3):

Although you could translate C# code to C++, there would be the issue that C# depends on the .Net framework libraries which are not native, so you could not simply translate C# code to C++.

**Update**

Also C# code depends on the runtime to do things such as memory management i.e. Garbage Collection. If you translated the C# code to C++, where would the memory management code be? Parsing and translating is not going to fix issues like that.

Comment: If he will be able to compile his own managed assemblies, what's the problem with compiling .NET ones?

Comment: @chibacity You mean that there are some classes in C# that aren't in C++

Comment: @taras I assume the OP would like to take the source code for a C# program, convert it to C++, and then compile it as a native C++ application. What I am saying is that even a basic C# application will depend on .Net framework libraries, so there is no such thing as taking the "C#" source and converting it to C++.

Comment: Sure, after "translating" C# sources to C++ (and compiling to native code), OP have to compile all dependent managed libs to native ones.

Comment: @taras I know you have mentioned NGen, but this doesn't really answer the translating to C++ bit. If I run my C# program the JIT will convert my IL to native code anyway. NGen just allows this to be done in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Mono project has invested quite a lot of energy in turning [LLVM into a native machine code compiler for the C# runtime](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_LLVM), although there are some problems with specific language constructs like [shared generics etc.](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aRuntime%3aDocumentation%3aLLVM). Check it out and take it for a spin.

Comment: "Limitations:

LLVM is not able to support some of the features that Mono needs, so in those cases the JIT compiler will still fall back to Mono's JIT engine (methods that contain try/catch clauses or methods that do interface calls)."

Comment: Often, just disabling shared generics is good enough to improve performance (just set `MONO_GENERIC_SHARING=none` in the environment) even without LLVM

Comment: @taras.roshko Yes, that is what I pointed out above :) There are specific ways to work around some of these limitations -- it's an investment you need to make, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to compile IL to native code

Comment: Which is normally not going to change anything except when modules are being loaded into different processes dynamically and repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

Performance related tweaks:

#### Platform independent

- use a profiler to spot the bottlenecks;

  - prevent unnecessary garbage (spot it using generation #0 collect count and the Large Object heap)
  - prevent unnecessary copying (use struct wisely)
  - prevent unwarranted generics (code-sharing has unexpected performance side effects)
  - prefer oldfashioned loops over enumerator blocks when performance is an issue
  - When using LINQ watch closely where you maintain/break deferred evaluation. Both can be enormous boosts to performance
- use reflection.emit/Expression Trees to precompile certain dynamic logic that is performance bottleneck

#### Mono

- use `Mono --gc=sgen --optimize=inline,...` (the SGEN garbage collector can make orders of magnitude difference). See also **[`man mono`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mono)** for a lot of tuning/optimization options
- use `MONO_GENERIC_SHARING=none` to disable sharing of generics (making particular tasks a lot quicker especially when supporting both valuetypes and reftypes) (*not recommended for regular production use*)
- use the `-optimize+` compile flag (optimizing the CLR code independently from what the JITter may do with that)

Less mainstream:

- use the LLVM backend (click the quote:)

  > [This allows Mono to benefit from all of the compiler optimizations done in LLVM. For example the SciMark score goes from 482 to 610.](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_LLVM)
- use **[mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Bundles)** to create a statically linked NATIVE binary image (already fully JITted, i.e. AOT (*ahead-of-time* compiled))

#### MS .NET

Most of the above have direct Microsoft pendants ([NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [`/Optimize'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0hfscdc.aspx) etc.)

Of course MS don't have a switchable/tunable garbage collector, and I don't think a fully compiled native binary can be achieved like with mono.

Answer (score 0):

As always the answer to making code run faster is:

**Find the bottleneck and optimize that**

Most of the time the bottleneck is either:

**time spend in a critical loop**
Review your algorithm and datastructure, do not change the language, the latter will give a 10% speedup, the first will give you a 1000x speedup.
If you're stuck on the best algorithm, you can always ask a **specific, short and detailed** question on SO.

**time waiting for resources for a slow source**
Reduce the amount of stuff you're requesting from the source
instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM bigtable
```

do

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM bigtable ORDER BY xxx
```

The latter will return instantly and you cannot show a million records in a meaningful way anyhow.
Or you can have the server at the order end reduce the data so that it doesn't take a 100 years to cross the network.

Alternativly you can execute the slow datafetch routine in a separate thread, so the rest of your program can do meaningful stuff instead of waiting.

**Time spend because you are overflowing memory with Gigabytes of data**
Use a different algorithm that works on a smaller dataset at a time.
Try to optimize cache usage.

**The answer to efficient coding is measure where your coding time goes**
Use a profiler.
see: http://csharp-source.net/open-source/profilers

And optimize those parts that eat more than 50% of your CPU time.
Do this for a number of iterations, and soon your 10 hour running time will be down to a manageable 3 minutes, instead of the 9.5 hours that you will get from switching to this or that better language.